# Port issue in Running Open LDAP container on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, openldap

I am trying to run and OpenLDAP container on Bluemix using IBM Containers. I am using cloudesire/openldap and sucessfully run the contianer on my local linux machine. I tried to run in my Bluemix account using IBM Container.

I am unable to test it using ldapsearch or telnet using port 389. I managed to run some other container and telnet them sucessfully, but not with Open LDAP container.

Is port 389 blocked by the Bluemix router? How proxy the port?

Comment: OpenLDAP isn't a container, it's a server. The port it listens to is defined in the configuration, and by default it is 389. *Ergo* if you can't connect to it on 389, either it isn't running or the configuration has changed the port, both of which you can check for yourself.. Off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Port 389 is currently blocked for IBM Containers running on Bluemix.
Please open a support ticket with IBM Bluemix Support and request this port to be exposed:

https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#support